# Does React have something similar to Angular's *ngIf?

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I trying to create a React component based on styled components. So far it looks something like this:

```
import { StyledComponent } from "./styles";

type ComponentProps = {
  icon: string;
  boldTxt?: string;
  normalTxt?: string;
};

const Component = ({ icon, boldTxt, normalTxt }: ComponentProps) => {
  return (
    <StyledComponent>
      <i className={icon}></i>
      <span>{boldTxt}</span>
      <span>{normalTxt}</span>
    </StyledComponent>
  );
};

export default Component;
```

In this case the content of the `StyledComponent` doesn't matter.

Since the `boldTxt` and `normalTxt` props are optional it's not always certain that there will be something in the `spans`. However, they will take up space even though they have no content.

In Angular I would just write something like:

```
<span *ngIf="boldTxt">{boldTxt}</span>
<span *ngIf="normalTxt">{normalTxt}</span>
```

And then the `spans` will only be rendered if they are not empty/null. Can this be achieved as elegantly in React, or...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing exactly like that, with an attribute. But perhaps:

```
const Component = ({ icon, boldTxt, normalTxt }: ComponentProps) => {
  return (
    <StyledComponent>
      <i className={icon}></i>
      {boldTxt && <span>{boldTxt}</span>}
      {normalTxt && <span>{normalTxt}</span>}
    </StyledComponent>
  );
};
```